# How to pull specific information out of a alarm event in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I set up a CPU alarm for an EC2 instance that triggers an SNS Topic that has an endpoint that is a Lambda function. The Lambda function will then send ma an email and slack message telling me that an instance is in the alarm start and tell me exactly what instance it came from. I have the email and slack working and now I just need to get the instance ID from the event that my Lambda received from the alarm.

I get the following event in the Lambda function. I want to just pull out the instance ID from it, which in this example would be "i-07db9e2f61d100". It is located in "Dimensions".

How about also pulling out the "AlarmName" (which would be "cpu-mon" in this example)?

Here is all the data in the event I receive:

```
{'Records': [{'EventSource': 'aws:sns', 'EventVersion': '1.0', 'EventSubscriptionArn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:Alarm-test:db99f3fe-1c4b', 'Sns': {'Type': 'Notification', 'MessageId': '9921c85a-6f59-50c0', 'TopicArn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:4990:Alarm-test', 'Subject': 'ALARM: "cpu-mon" in US East (Ohio)', 'Message': '{"AlarmName":"cpu-mon","AlarmDescription":"Alarm when CPU exceeds 70 percent","AWSAccountId":"000000000","NewStateValue":"ALARM","NewStateReason":"Threshold Crossed: 2 out of the last 2 datapoints [99.8333333333333 (26/08/19 19:19:00), 99.1803278688525 (26/08/19 19:18:00)] were greater than the threshold (70.0) (minimum 2 datapoints for OK -> ALARM transition).","StateChangeTime":"2019-08-26T19:20:52.350+0000","Region":"US East (Ohio)","OldStateValue":"OK","Trigger":{"MetricName":"CPUUtilization","Namespace":"AWS/EC2","StatisticType":"Statistic","Statistic":"AVERAGE","Unit":"Percent","Dimensions":[{"value":"i-07db9e2f61d100","name":"InstanceId"}],"Period":60,"EvaluationPeriods":2,"ComparisonOperator":"GreaterThanThreshold","Threshold":70.0,"TreatMissingData":"","EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile":""}}', 'Timestamp': '2019-08-26T19:20:52.403Z', 'SignatureVersion': '1', 'Signature': 'UeWhS==', 'SigningCertUrl': 'https://sns.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-63f9.pem', 'UnsubscribeUrl': 'https://sns.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:49:Alarm-test:dfe-1c4b-4db9', 'MessageAttributes': {}}}]}
```

Here is my Lambda function (python) -

```
# Sends Slack and text message

import json
import subprocess
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(
    region_name="us-east-1"
)

sns_client = session.client('sns')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("THIS IS THE EVENT - " + str(event))
    data = json.dumps({'text': str(event)})

    # Send text alerts
    alertNumbers = ["1-xxx-xxx-xxxx"]


    # Send text message
    for i in range(len(alertNumbers)):
        sns_client.publish(
        PhoneNumber=alertNumbers[i],
        Message=msg,
        MessageAttributes={
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {
                'DataType': 'String',
                'StringValue': 'SENDERID'
            },
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': {
                'DataType': 'String',
                'StringValue': 'Promotional'
            }
        }
        )

    # Send Slack message
    subprocess.call([
    'curl',
    '-X', 'POST',
    '-H', 'Content-type: application/json',
    '--data', data,
    'https://hooks.slack.com/services/000000'
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What language are you using and what have you tried? Feel free to edit your question to provide more information so the community can assist.

Comment: I added it. Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: Hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to access the data of the event and put it where you want it.

Inside your `lambda_handler` add this as the first line:

`message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])`

Now the SNS message is available as `message`. To get the `AlarmName` is as simple as `message['AlarmName']` and the instance id is at `message['Trigger']['Dimensions'][0]['value']`

Comment: Message is of type string. You need to use json.loads(message) to convert it to a dictionary before accessing its fields.

Comment: I missed that in the message... Editted.

Comment: That works! Now I know how to navigate around JSON. Thanks so much!!

Comment: My pleasure! Don't forget to accept it as the accepted answer. Good luck with your project!